# JavaMail throws MailConnectException on Linux VPS but works locally at Windows machine

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, tomcat9

I am trying to run spring boot web app at Linux VPS (Debian 10 release).

I am using JavaMail api for building and sending welcome messages when users sing up to the page.

Works perfectly when running locally at windows 10 machine, using tomcat 9.

After deploying to the VPS tomcat 9, exception occurs when trying to send a mail.

There is stacktrace:

```
 [2020-04-02 16:49:34] [info]
 org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server connection
 failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException:
 Couldn't connect to host, port: mail.mydomain.hr, 587; timeout -1;
 [2020-04-02 16:49:34] [info]   nested exception is: [2020-04-02
 16:49:34] [info] #011java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
 (Connection timed out). Failed messages:
 com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host,
 port: mail.mydomain.hr, 587; timeout -1;
```

There are application.properties

```
spring.mail.host=mail.mydomain.hr
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=info@mydomain.hr
spring.mail.password=mypass
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Firewall problem. Talk to your provider about how to send mail.

Comment: Is the connection from your vps to the mail host enabled? What's the output of nc -zv mail.mydomain.hr 587?

Comment: @lainatnavi first DNS fwd/rev mismatch, then connection timed out. 
When trying same locally from my Mac result is:
Connection to mail.mydomain.hr port 587 [tcp/submission] succeeded!

Comment: @spalatrin is the mail server on the same VPS where you're running tomcat? Does the nc succeed if you use the IP address instead of the DNS? Do you have control over the mail server? Try adding as much details as possible. Check this post, it seems to me it's related to your problem: https://serverfault.com/questions/468855/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch

Comment: @lainatnavi no its not on the same server. No nc doesnt succed from VPS when using ip instead of DNS.  But succeeds from my Mac machine when using bot, ip or DNS. Yes I have control over the mail server.

Comment: @lainatnavi nc -zv to the port 80 returns:
mail.mydomain.hr [IP ADDRESS] 80 (http) open

Looks like the problem is for port 587.

Comment: @spalatrin then check the firewall. Try to replicate the rule that allow your Mac machine's public IP connect to the mail server for your VPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by these two steps:

Changed VPS rDNS to mydomain.hr - (I am not sure if this was necessary)

Contacted my support to restart firewall and it is working now. So it was firewall problem.